# Как в git восстановить изначальный коммит после --amend?

Tags: git, восстановление

Зафиксировал изменения, затем внёс несколько мелких правок, пересохранил зафиксированные изменения с помощью `git commit --amend`.

Можно ли как-то восстановить состояние дерева до вышеприведенной команды?

Пробовал `git log --all` и `git reflog`, это зафиксированное изменение до правок не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

В `git reflog` должно быть.

```
$ git reflog 
d8bbc01 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
680cfc5 HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): 111
d8bbc01 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{2}: commit: 111
968a408 HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): init
```

Comment: Насколько вижу по вашему примеру, каждый amend коммит должен иметь свой индекс. У меня вроде такая же ситуация по отношению к старым коммитом, но для последнего (нужного) нет ничего похожего: 
3e4af79 (HEAD -> hw_testing) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD

3e4af79 (HEAD -> hw_testing) HEAD@{1}: commit: Отладил DAC2 на передатчике. Еще что-то по мелочи.

5576b23 HEAD@{2}: commit: Отладил генерацию синуса аудиоподнесущей DDS2, косяк с номером бита

c976421 HEAD@{3}: commit (amend): Проверил работу реле, исправил  косяки в их управлении. (почему-то в комментарии нельзя делать абзацы)

Comment: `c976421 HEAD@{3}: commit (amend)` ну вот это же amend предыдущего коммита

Comment: Забыл добавить, я не менял сообщение коммита (когда сделал коммит через amend), а только код. Т.е. должно быть несколько коммитов с одним и тем же сообщением. И интересует "Отладил dac2...".